# Using MahApps Icons with ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, mahapps.metro

I am writing a WPF application using the MahApps Metro UI toolkit.

http://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html

From the guide on their website, I have basically finished my application and it looks slick. The only issue I have is I have not been able to find out how to use the icon packs they provide as contextmenu icons.

[image]

Here's an visual example of what I'm trying to do. While I was able to get the original "Windows" menu item to display it's icon, I am unable to do the same for the contextmenu menuitems. Is there something I am doing wrong or a way to work around this?

Here's my .xaml:

```
<Menu IsMainMenu="True">
    <MenuItem Header="_Windows" ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="False" Click="WindowsMenuItem_Click">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Rectangle Width="15" Height="15" Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}, Path=Foreground}">
                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_window}" />
                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            </Rectangle>
        </MenuItem.Icon>
        <MenuItem.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="_Welcome Module">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Rectangle Width="15" Height="15" Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}, Path=Foreground}">
                            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_home}" />
                            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Schedule Module">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Rectangle Width="15" Height="15" Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}, Path=Foreground}">
                            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_calendar}" />
                            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Performance Module">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Rectangle Width="15" Height="15" Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}, Path=Foreground}">
                            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_table}" />
                            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Audit Module">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Rectangle Width="15" Height="15" Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}, Path=Foreground}">
                            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_graph_line}" />
                            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </MenuItem.ContextMenu>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

And my .xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }

    private void WindowsMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as MenuItem).ContextMenu.IsEnabled = true;
        (sender as MenuItem).ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = (sender as MenuItem);
        (sender as MenuItem).ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom;
        (sender as MenuItem).ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I got it to work in my application using:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
      <VisualBrush x:Key="RunAllTestsIcon" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_list_check}"/>
   </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
... 
<ContextMenu StaysOpen="True">
   <MenuItem Header="RunAllTests">
      <MenuItem.Icon>
         <Rectangle Width="22" Height="22" Fill="{StaticResource RunAllTestsIcon}"/>
      </MenuItem.Icon>
   </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by using a vector icon directly without having to embed the image or change the resource file.

```
<MenuItem Header="_Reload Data" Click="alleTaken22_Click">
    <MenuItem.Icon>

        <Viewbox Width="22" Height="22">
            <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
                <Path Data="M12,5V1L7,6L12,11V7A6,6 0 0,1 18,13A6,6 0 0,1 12,19A6,6 0 0,1 6,13H4A8,8 0 0,0 12,21A8,8 0 0,0 20,13A8,8 0 0,0 12,5Z" Fill="#FFFFFF" />
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>

    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

The vector icon comes from [materialdesignicons.com](https://materialdesignicons.com/). You can select an icon and get the `Path` for XAML directly from there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the latest MahApps IconPacks you can simply do the following:

```
xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
    

<MenuItem.Icon>
   <iconPacks:PackIconForkAwesome Kind="Calendar" Width="20" Height="20"/>
</MenuItem.Icon>
```