# Visual brush as an icon in the ContextMenu wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

**I want to use Visual Brush as an icon in the context menu** (of treeview) in my wpf usercontrol.

I have a resource dictionary (separate icon xaml file), few lines from the file are given below:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<VisualBrush x:Key="Trashcan"
             Stretch="Uniform">
```

I have merged the dictionaries in the usercontrol, and also checked that it has been added and can be accessed in the usercontrol xaml code.

The code in the usercontrol xaml (view) is given below, where the icons have to be used

```
 <ContextMenu x:Key=xxxxxxxx>
                <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding xxxxxx, Source=xxxxxxx}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" IsEnabled="xxxxxxxxxx}" Icon="{StaticResource Trashcan}"/>
 </ContextMenu>
```

Now the issue is **I am unable to see the icons** in the context menu, picture is attached below:

[image]

So far, I have tried the approach given in this link [Using MahApps Icons with ContextMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35671346/using-mahapps-icons-with-contextmenu) but didnt quite work for me.

**Is there some way other than the one in the above mentioned link that could be used to show visual brush as an icon in the context menu.**

**NOTE**: I cannot use the menuitem.icon -> image, as I have restrictions coming from other components of the application.

**NOTE**: I dont know whether it is important to state here that a **Form** is hosting my **WPF usercontrol**.

Comment: what did you expect? there is no image in the `ResourceDictionary`

Comment: ok, yes, I also tried to change the visual brush to image but I was unsuccessful. is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to set an `Image` to the `MenuItem.Icon`.

```
<MenuItem.Icon>
     <Image Style="{StaticResource Trashcan}"/>
</MenuItem.Icon>
```

Define a style for that image in the resource dictionary:

```
<Style x:Key="Trashcan" TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/ProjectName;component/Images/Trashcan.png"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="24"/>
</Style>
```

---

### added:

If you can't use `MenuItem.Icon` here's a trick you can do:

```
<MenuItem.Header>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="........"/>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="24" Margin="-24,0,0,0" 
               Style="{StaticResource Trashcan}"/>
    </Grid>
</MenuItem.Header>
```

Comment: I know this thats why in my question there is a line:
"I cannot use the menuitem.image as I have restrictions coming from other components of the application." The idea behind using brush instead of image is that it changes color on selection but image does not and I want to change the color of the icon when there is selection on it

Comment: btw. if you want to change image color there are many libraries that can do that to images in runtime. e.g. GrayscaleEffect

Comment: @stalbaig, in this case I think you need to make some editing to your question regarding the VisualBrush-related parts of your code or maybe ask another one. see this post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c7e116b7-6b66-4c6d-ac00-20e7b781aabd/visual-brush-of-a-windowsformhost?forum=wpf